# Dynamically rename columns in room table using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, migration, android-room

I have an application which loads a csv file with 4 fixed columns and 3 optional. I create tables in a room with 7 columns, where the last 3 have a name (atr1, atr2, atr3) and take a value of the String type. Is there a way to use Kotlin to rename these columns depending on the value in the csv file? Or is it possible to create 4 columns in the room and then add more depending on the columns in the csv file?

Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "IND1")
data class IND1(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "ID") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nr") val number: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date: LocalDate,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr1") val atr1: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr2") val atr2: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr3") val atr3: String?
)
```

Database

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(IND1::class, STT4::class, UNT1::class, USR1::class, WHS1::class), version = 2, exportSchema = true)
@TypeConverters(DateTimeConverter::class )
abstract class LocalRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun roomDao(): RoomDao
}
```

Module in dagger

```
@Module
object DatabaseModule {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(applicationContext: MobileApplication): LocalRoomDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, LocalRoomDatabase::class.java, "local_database")
            .addTypeConverter(DateTimeConverter())
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDao(database: LocalRoomDatabase) = database.roomDao()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use Kotlin to rename these columns depending on the value in the csv file?

Not with Room as you would have issues with the Entities and the underlying generated code.

> Or is it possible to create 4 columns in the room and then add more depending on the columns in the csv file?

Again no. As again basically Room creates and expects the tables to conform to the Entities.

**However**, a solution would be to have a table (Entity) for the items in the list/csv. Each related to the respective row in the IND1 table.

For example **IND1** could become :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "IND1")
data class IND1(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "ID") val id: Long, /* should really be Long */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "nr") val number: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date: String /* Change for convenience */,

    /* MOVED
    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr1") val atr1: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr2") val atr2: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "atr3") val atr3: String?

     */
)
```

- i.e. the attributes will be stored in a related table with a 1-many relationship (1 IND1 can have many attributes (0+)).
- the **ID** column, as it uniquely identifies the IND1 row is a (the best) candidate for the relationship.

So the other table/entity could be **Attribute** :-

```
@Entity (
    /* Foreign Key is optional but recommended to enforce
        referential integrity
     */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = IND1::class,
            parentColumns = ["ID"],
            childColumns = ["IND1_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
        )
data class Attribute(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "AttributeId") val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IND1_id", index = true) val parent_IND1: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "attribute") val atr: String
)
```

- the **IND1_id** column is used for the relationship i.e. it is the ID of the  owning (parent) IND1.

To combine into a single object you could have a POJO (i.e. not an actual table and therefore not an entity) such as **IND1WithAttributes** :-

```
data class IND1WithAttributes(
    @Embedded
    val ind1: IND1,
    @Relation(entity = Attribute::class,parentColumn = "ID",entityColumn = "IND1_id")
    val attributes: List<Attribute>
)
```

You would then retrieve the combined IND1 and it's attributes using a query such as

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM ind1")
fun getAllIND1sWithAttributes(): List<IND1WithAttributes>
```

As an example of using the above, the following was used (not using Dagger) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        /* Add some data */
        val item1Id = dao.insert(IND1(1,100,"Item1","2021-06-25"))
        dao.insert(Attribute(1,item1Id,"First Attribute in List"))
        dao.insert(Attribute(2,item1Id,"Second Attribute"))
        dao.insert(Attribute(3,item1Id,"Third Attribute"))

        /* extract the data and output to the log */
        for(iwa: IND1WithAttributes in dao.getAllIND1sWithAttributes()) {
            Log.d("IND1INFO","IND1 Name = ${iwa.ind1.name} number = ${iwa.ind1.number} date = ${iwa.ind1.date} id = ${iwa.ind1.id}")
            for(a: Attribute in iwa.attributes) {
                Log.d("IND1INFO","\tAttribute = ${a.atr} id = ${a.id} id of parent IND1 = ${a.parent_IND1}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above and the Log shows :-

```
2021-06-25 23:31:38.064 D/IND1INFO: IND1 Name = Item1 number = 100 date = 2021-06-25 id = 1
2021-06-25 23:31:38.064 D/IND1INFO:     Attribute = First Attribute in List id = 1 id of parent IND1 = 1
2021-06-25 23:31:38.064 D/IND1INFO:     Attribute = Second Attribute id = 2 id of parent IND1 = 1
2021-06-25 23:31:38.064 D/IND1INFO:     Attribute = Third Attribute id = 3 id of parent IND1 = 1
```